# laravel 5 - how to create custom log levels?

Tags: php, logging, laravel-5, monolog

I want to log user actions, app requests, etc... Something like:

```
[2015-04-23 20:40:36] user.register {"name":"mike", "age":"35"}
[2015-04-23 20:40:55] user.login    {"user_id":123}
```

All of entries should go to a separated files by action type.

Can I do this using Laravel 5 Monolog library? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you **could** create a new loglevel; but I recommend you to use [Model Events](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-events).

For example; on user registration:

```
User::creating(function($user)
{
    \Log::info('user.register '.$user->toJson());
});
```